# Virtual machine undoing

Tags: virtual-machine

I am working with fairly sensitive information and I am also just a very paranoid person in general. I am using my work computer, but seeing as how I don't work for a company, I don't have any way of safely wiping everything completely whenever I decide to get rid of it. I mean, I can have somebody wipe it for me (I just don't know how secure it is) or just destroy the computer, but outside of that I am not sure what I can do.

So I was thinking about using a Virtual Machine, but I don't understand much about it. For example, I see [this article about internet browsing, sandboxing, and an "undo" feature](http://www.devx.com/vmspecialreport/Article/30377). I realize this is about internet browsing, but the idea of whenever I close the application and it deleting from the VM is appealing. However, I've also read things where you can use VMWare Tools or something like that to recover data that you deleted on the VM.

Is it possible to have the VM delete the data and, at least, make it virtually impossible to recover the data? If not completely, at least make it very unlikely?

Comment: Is there something I can do to improve the question? I understand that there are some strict rules as to how to ask a question, but without any feedback, I can't improve it.

Comment: I think this is question is generally out of scope for this site, since it is not about a specific programming problem.

Comment: Gotcha. Is there a different stackoverflow site that is more keen on this?

Comment: Maybe https://superuser.com/ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The VM's storage is an abstraction and compartmentalization of the storage on the host machine. You can delete the VM, but recovering its *image* and therefore its contents is not any harder than using forensic tools to recover regular files on your device. If you're worried about security, use strong passwords and a VPN service. In terms of file destruction, you can simply encrypt your data before "destruction". This way even if someone recovers it, it'll be *computationally infeasible* * for them to undo the encryption just for the chance to *maybe* peek at your files.

*Computational infeasibility means a computation which although computable would take far too many resources to actually compute. Ideally in cryptography one would like to ensure an infeasible computation’s cost is greater than the reward obtained by computing it.*

Comment: Interesting. Thanks. So a VM is not an ideal way to make things more secure? That's unfortunate. I have this hard drive encrypted on my actual computer, but I was hoping that the VM would make it even more private.

Comment: VMs are good from an internet security perspective as it's very hard to get from INSIDE the VM to the host machine. The reverse however is very easy and not secure.

Comment: Ooohhh, okay. That makes sense as to why that article was specifically about internet browsing. That's not really what I am looking for.